# Creating an Emoji-Like Keyboard

Tags: ios, emoji

I am looking to create an emoji keyboard, which works similar to the native one on iPhone.

Currently all apps that provide a keyboard, do not let you insert an emoji inline with the text.. rather they provide you the ability to 'paste' it in like an image.

In addition to this, if an emoji is sent to a user that doesnt have the app installed, will they see the 'emoji' or will it display as a bunch of random characters?

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, as I cannot find the detail I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Every app I have every seen and used lets you type in standard Emoji characters inline with any other text. Simply enable the Emoji keyboard (and any other keyboards the user might want) in the Settings app and now I can select that keyboard when I type text into a text field or text view. This is standard iOS functionality. No special app is required.

Answer (score 0):

As for creating custom keyboards, you should get started by reading [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) on the subject.

To answer your question about displaying Emoji: Any platform that supports Emoji will see them as an Emoji. A good source to see which platforms support it is [CanIEmoji.com](http://caniemoji.com/). Any other platforms will likely display it as an empty square, since it is not a supported character.

Answer (score 0):

Any custom emoji keyboard you create will show up like a picture attachment, iOS especially doesn't allow custom inline emojis.  Check out these two articles they might help with even more info:

- https://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/blog/emoji-apps/
- https://medium.com/@mantia/so-you-want-to-build-an-emoji-keyboard-26450ba5136a